# Why am I getting bad results from Table?

Tags: function-construction, list-manipulation

Here is my code. Why Won't it tabulate? What am I doing wrong?

```
Table[0.10/(0.10 + (1.0 - 0.10)*(Exp[-0.0439445*t]))[t], {t, 0, 100, 10.0}] 

{0.1`/1. `[0.`], 
 0.1`/0.679954564454369`[10.`], 
 0.1`/0.4737192187016187`[20.`], 
 0.1`/0.34082240745591597`[30.`], 
 0.1`/0.2551845049188315`[40.`], 
 0.1`/0.19999995773363088`[50.`], 
 0.1`/0.1644393688142925`[60.`], 
 0.1`/0.14152434008267495`[70.`], 
 0.1`/0.12675803396322538`[80.`], 
 0.1`/0.1172427154808862`[90.`], 
 0.1`/0.11111110171858662`[100.`]}
```

Comment: The `[t]` is too much. When you leave it out, do you get the result you expected?

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke I think OP wanted to make a function inside the table. At least that is what I understood :)

Answer (score 3):

if you meant for it to be a function, better to define one outside

```
foo[t_] := 0.10/(0.10 + (1.0 - 0.10)*(Exp[-0.0439445*t]))
Table[foo[t], {t, 0, 100, 10.0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To put it inside you can try

```
Table[Function[0.10/(0.10 + (1.0 - 0.10)*(Exp[-0.0439445*t]))][t], {t,
   0, 100, 10.0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I think putting the function outside is more clear.